# How to render Ckeditor 5 text as it is with tailwind css?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor5

Hi I am using Ckeditor with vue3 and tailwind css . But the text produced by rich edior is rendering as a p tag . No tags like ul ol and table are working .

```
<script>
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { reactive } from 'vue';
export default {
    setup(){
        const state=reactive({
            editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
                editorConfig: {
                    
                }
        })

        return {state}
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div id="vk">
        <ckeditor :editor="state.editor" v-model="state.editorData" :config="state.editorConfig"></ckeditor>
    </div>
    
        <div id="description" v-html="state.editorData">

        </div>
    
</template>

<style scoped>
    
</style>
``
```

Comment: CKEditor works like crap with Laravel/Tailwind... basically only the ClassicEditor without any extra modules work.. otherwise all hell breaks free.

Horrible experience here.. spent 2 days trying to get image resizing to work with that shitty nested css they do. tried all sorts of magic, packages, tweaked different conf files.. made it accept nested css as mentioned in their docs.. tried ChatGPT... nothing.. to hell with this modular package shit.

Answer (score 2):

Now `ckeditor-tailwind-reset` plugin is [deprecated](https://github.com/RSurya99/ckeditor-tailwind-reset) since `tailwind` has an [official plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) `tailwind-typography`, so you don't need to use this to add beautiful default typographic. Except for the table, maybe you can just copy some CSS from this package into your project CSS.

Just install:

```
npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography
```

Extend config:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Add `prose` class wherever you need, and it ignores tailwind css:

```
<article class="prose">
  {{ markdown }}
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this package [RSurya99/ckeditor-tailwind-reset](https://github.com/RSurya99/ckeditor-tailwind-reset), it worked for me.

So, basically you just to install the package

```bash
npm i ckeditor-tailwind-reset
```

and import styles in your app

```scss
@import 'ckeditor-tailwind-reset/ckeditor-tailwind-reset';
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33309709)